# Unable to scan Code 128 with Zxing Android

Tags: android, barcode, zxing, code128

I have integrated the ZXing barcode reader in my android application.

It scans most of the codes, but I have a electricity bill which it is unable to scan (using a Galaxy Ace 5.0MP). I think the problem is due to camera resolution and focus, because when I tried the same barcode on using Xperia SL (12.1MP) I got the result. So is there any solution to this problem?

I have attached a sample image of the barcode.

[image: valid XHTML]
.

Comment: it is true that code is a bit long, but if u position camera so it fit just exactly in scanning rectangle everything should be with scanning..

Comment: I tried your code with my Xperia mini pro 5MP using NeoReader app, and with no luck.. may be code is too lengthy

Comment: ya its maybe due to the length i guess...But is there a solution to this problem???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This scans instantly by the library itself:

http://zxing.org/w/decode?u=http%3A%2F%2Fs8.postimage.org%2Fhohyonvzp%2FBSESExample.png

It may be down to your camera, yes. I don't think you are doing anything wrong.

Comment: It scans easily off the screen with Barcode Scanner on my device. Resolution has nothing to do with it; focus might. You can try different apps like https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.srowen.bs.android

Comment: @SeanOwen aaah providing a link to your paid app on play store.. haha, but will it do any good.

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was well known that I develop both Barcode Scanner and Barcode Scanner+. I will undo your transaction. The problem is your device then.

Comment: May be.. not sure but i also tried it on xperia tipo...Still no luck...Will try it on s2 and s3 again and check...